# what does `echo in_memory` do?

Tags: shell, dockerfile

While going through the [dockerfile](https://github.com/sekka1/mesosphere-docker/blob/master/mesos-master/Dockerfile) I came across this line-
`echo in_memory | sudo dd of=/some/path/`
Its a shell command. I googled it but I'm not satisfied with the answers. Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems quite simple:

```
echo in_memory
```

writes the string "in_memory" to the standard output

```
echo in_memory | sudo dd of=/some/path
```

writes the string "in_memory" into "/some/path"

Comment: It means `ìn_memory` is not a keyword.  and what about `dd of=/some/path` ?

Comment: @YogeshJilhawar Well... `dd` is just `dd`. It copies and optionally convert (but this is not the case) data from its input (either standard input or `if=InputFile`) and writes data to output (either standard output or `of=OutputFile`). More info [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html)